# Why can't we use a CALL :label command in the FORFILES script?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, method-call, forfiles

This snippet of code

```
forfiles /P %pathname% /M *.log /c "cmd /c echo @file"
```

will happily list out a bunch of files.

We could replace the `ECHO` with `RENAME` or `MOVE` or many other combinations of internal commands: the exception being a `CALL` to a label name.

For instance replacing the `ECHO` above as follows:

```
forfiles /P %pathname% /M *.log /c "cmd /c CALL :listit @file"
 : :
 : :
exit /b

:listit
echo %1
exit /b
```

Which I would have hoped would have the same output gives an error message, typically

```
Invalid attempt to call batch label outside of batch script.
```

This behaviour is not something that Microsoft's documentation remarks on, and since the alternatives are perfectly adequate, I've not gone looking to make it work.

But I am interested in the *Well, why not?!*, and so I'm posing the Question

**Why can't we use a CALL :label command in the FORFILES script?**

Thank you.

Comment: `cmd /c` opens a new instance of `cmd`. So the following is just a single command line; there is no context of a batch file. You can use `for` instead: `for %%a in ("%pathname%\*.log) do call :listit "%%a"`

Comment: It's because the call instruction you are using is being run within another cmd.exe instance not as part of your batch files cmd.exe instance.

Comment: [@Stephan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2152082/stephan), thanks, yes that is what I have used.

Comment: [@Compo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6738015/compo) yes, I wondered if that might not be the case, so I tried a `CALL :listit.bat @file` as an alternative, reasoning that would work, but hmmm ... no it didn't.

Comment: That is no different, you cannot call a label with an argument, in a separate cmd.exe instance and expect it to work like that. As you don't appear to be using `forfiles` for something specific, _like incorporating its `/D` option_, you may wish to consider `findstr /m "^" "%pathname%\*.log"` as an alternative.

Comment: The `CALL :label` statement is for calling a label inside the current batch file. Use `CALL listit.bat @file` instead. See https://ss64.com/nt/call.html

Comment: [@Compo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6738015/compo) you are right, that is a very limited script, to ilustrate the problem so that I could get an understanding of the "why" which has been explained very well.

Comment: [DodgyCodeException](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8473028/dodgycodeexception) Thanks for the reference, yes, I've had a read of SS64,before posing the Q and also Rob van der Woude, it didn't seem to give me the answer. But I understand the principle clearly enough now. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @Stephan commented already, it can't uses labels, because it's executed in a command line context.

In most of the cases you can use the simpler `FOR` command.

But in cases where you need `forfiles` and labels, this can be solved with a simple trick.

1. At the begin of your batch file you need the line `FOR /F ... goto :%%L`.
2. And when calling the label it has to be enclosed `forfiles ... call %~d0\:<myLabel>:\..\%~pn0`

```
@echo off
FOR /F "tokens=3 delims=:" %%L in ("%~0") DO goto :%%L

...
forfiles /P %pathname% /M *.log /c "cmd /c CALL %~d0\:listit:\..\%~pn0 @file"
...

:listit
echo %1
exit /b
```

A good advice from aschipfl:
To add some more stability (against spaces in the path/filename) you can enclose the call destination into quotes `call 0x22%~d0\:listit:\..\%~pn00x22 @file`.

This is a special syntax only in `forfiles`, where `0xHH` is the hexadecimal code for the character `0x22="`.

Comment: Thanks [Jeb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/463115/jeb) that's a great piece of scripting

Comment: So the purpose of embedding the jump label into the script path is to not alter the number of arguments and therefore the output of `%*` then, right? I'd put the script path in between (escaped) quotes: `0x22%~d0\:listit:\..\%~pn00x22`...

Comment: @aschipfl You are right. This technique doesn't influence the normal behaviour of a script, especially when it already uses `%1`... And it's a generic trampoline to any function. I heavily use it in my batchLibrary

Comment: gets better and better... that's a deep apreciation of what's happening in the engine room.

Comment: @jeb can you provide a reference for this? I tried it but it does not seem to jump to the specified label. As I understand, it basically does this `cmd /c D:\:mylabel:\..\myscript arg1`, correct? I also tried running this directly on the commandline but it does not work.

Comment: @kapitanluffy Did you add some debugging code to the first `FOR /F "tokens=3 ...`? If the problem still persists you should ask a separate question